# Reference the correct static file in phoenix

Tags: caching, elixir, phoenix-framework

In a phoenix project, I can reference digested img in a css file with:

```
background-image: url("/images/phoenix.png");
```

and that references:

```
http://localhost:4000/images/phoenix-5bd99a0d17dd41bc9d9bf6840abcc089.png?vsn=d
```

I would like to reference the same file, but the image `src` added with javascript, like so:

```
document.querySelector('#my-img').src = '/images/phoenix.png';
```

But this only references:

```
http://localhost:4000/images/phoenix.png
```

How can I configure the phoenix endpoint to instead serve the digested img file?

(I would like this functionality for updating cached file purposes)

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the image file beforehand, you can have a javascript variable and set the value to the URL to that image file and use it later in your script

Something like this in your .eex template:

```
<script>
 // using static_path(@conn, "/path/to/asset") will give the digested file url
 var disgestedImageUrl ="<%= static_path(@conn, "/images/phoenix.png") %>";
</script>
```

Then have your script that uses the URL in your .js file

```
<script>
  document.querySelector('#my-img').src = digesterImageUrl;
</script>
```